# Find and remove part of string and again add that part with new value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Below is my connection string which is used at so many places.

```
<add key="conString" value="Data Source=My-Pc;Initial Catalog=Db1;User ID=sdfsdf;Password=facebook"></add>
```

Now at first I want to remove **initialcatalog** part from the connection string along with the database and later on I want to add **initialcatalog** part with new database name.

Below is the code:

```
public void statistics()
{
   String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conString"];
   //here i want to remove this part :  Initial Catalog=Db1;
   connString = "Data Source=My-Pc;User ID=sdfsdf;Password=facebook";

   //Here I have lots of operation and after that I would like to add this part with new database name

   string newDb= "db2";
   //again add that part with new db :  Initial Catalog=Db2;
   connString = "Data Source=My-Pc;Initial Catalog=Db2;User ID=sdfsdf;Password=facebook";
}
```

Comment: Downvoter please give me the reason for downvoting??

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create multiple configs with relative paths and then at runtime decide which one to use?

Comment: @juharr:Ok with using SqlConnectionStringBuilder i can remove that whole part of intial catalog but then how i will add it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// initialize ConnectionStringBuilder like so:
String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conString"];

var builder = new ConnectionStringBuilder(connString);
// set initial catalog to other database: 
builder.InitialCatalog = "<otherDatabaseName>";
// retrieve new connectionstring
var newConnectionString = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Your answer really helped me.Once again thank you so much and please keep helping like this :)